# WPF ListView binding update selected index

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a ListView with a list of string:

```
        <ListView
            SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=DBProvider.CurrentPartIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Margin="20,20,20,0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Name="ListViewItem"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            Background="#DCE3E5">
                    <ListView.Resources>

                        <!-- Template that is used upon selection of an Area -->
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="SelectedTemplate" TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Border Background="#388095" Cursor="Hand" >
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5" />
                            </Border>                                
                        </ControlTemplate>

                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>                                        
                                    <!-- Base Template that is replaced upon selection -->
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                        <Border Background="#DCE3E5" Cursor="Hand"  >
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5" />
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}" />
                                </MultiTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>

                    </ListView.Resources>   
        </ListView>
```

I want to update the selected item from it with an int CurrentPartIndex in a singleton "DBProvider.CurrentPartIndex".
I can access the DBProvider with this in the xaml.cs:

```
        public DBProvider DBProviderInstance
        {
            get { return DBProvider.Instance; }
        }
```

The supposed to be index value:

```
        public int _currentPartIndex = 0;
        public int CurrentPartIndex
        {
            set
            {
                _currentPartIndex = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPartIndex");
            }
            get
            {
                return _currentPartIndex;
            }
        }
```

My problem is that I can't update visually the selected item. When I fill the listview, the setter is triggered but when I change CurrentPartIndex it doesn't do anything.
I need a way to show which item is selected, as if it were selected by the user.

Comment: Do you notice any data binding error message in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you debug the application? IMO the Binding should be `SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=DBProviderInstance.CurrentPartIndex}"`

Comment: What collection does the ListView display?
Where is the ItemsSource binding?
It is better to use SelectedItem to get the selected item.
SelectedIndex returns the index in the ListView, but this index will not necessarily match the index of the selected item in the original collection.

Comment: Clemens was right. The head in the code I did not notice anything and the code was way to okay.
Thank you very mush.